# VBnet MSword Automation "Replace Text"

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I would like to do a replace all using VBnet 2003 and MSword 2007.

I got to this

```
Dim Selection As Word.Selection
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting()
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Underline = Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Text"
    .Replacement.Text = "Replacement"
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchFuzzy = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute(Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
```

It crashes EVERY line with the selection claiming that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I got the code by doing a macro recording and it worked fine as a macro but I do not want macros in my document. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to link to Word and the document.  This code assumes Word is running with the correct document loaded and displayed.

```
Dim WordApplication As Word.Application = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Dim Document As Word.Document = WordApplication.ActiveDocument
Document.Select()
Dim Selection As Word.Selection = Document.ActiveWindow.Selection
' Do your thing here.
```

Comment: All i needed was Dim Selection As Word.Selection = Document.ActiveWindow.Selection